# Editing error messages of username field in django RegistrationForm

Tags: django, django-forms, django-registration

i am trying to change some error messages in django's default registration form:

```
class RegistrationForm(forms.Form):
    username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_("Username"),error_messages={'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters,numbers and underscores.")})
    email=forms.EmailField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict,maxlength=75)),label=_("Email address"))
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict,render_value=False),label=_("Password"))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=attrs_dict,render_value=False),label=_("Password (again)"))
```

**for example i want to change**

'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters,numbers and underscores.") of username field 
whenever i edit the default form it shows me no change...even i tried with chmod...

Also suggest me if there is way to restrict user to enter only digits in username field...

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code in django.forms.field (lines 423 to 439) (on django 1.3.1).

You notice that for a RegexField, django overrides error_messages['invalid'] with a keyword argument error_message, which defaults to none.

So if you want to keep a RegexField simply do :

```
username = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\w+$',max_length=30,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict),label=_("Username"),error_message = _("This value must contain only letters,numbers and underscores."))
```

To accept only digits as a username, I would recommend using a forms.IntegerField, that would give something along the lines of :

```
username = forms.IntegerField(min_value = 0, error_messages={'invalid': _("This value must contain only letters,numbers and underscores.")})
```

Using an IntegerField is in my opinion the cleanest and nicest way to do it. And it does what you want : restricting the username to digits only.

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply.I didnt know that editing in the custom form would replace the field settings